# What is the correct path for zbarlight using Python 3?

Tags: python, path, zbar

I am attempting to run zbarlight for the first time, I am using the recommended script.

```
from PIL import Image
import zbarlight

file_path = './tests/fixtures/two_qr_codes.png'
with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file:
    image = Image.open(image_file)
    image.load()

codes = zbarlight.scan_codes('qrcode', image)
print('QR codes: %s' % codes)
```

Please see below

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/zbarlight/1.0.0

I am however getting the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/JamesParsons/Dropbox/Python/carpark.py", line 6, in 
>       with open(file_path, 'rb') as image_file: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   './tests/fixtures/two_qr_codes.png'

What would be the best way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Give the right path to the png file.

Comment: Have you got any experience with zbarlight, what program would I need to boot the camera to scan the code to that path? @Klaus D.

Comment: That's a completely different question. One question per question here on SO.

Comment: Your right it is, you are correct!